# Contact Form 7 Default value from url

Tags: plugins, plugin-contact-form-7, customization

I have a contact form . I want to set default value by url . For example my contact form url is that

```
http://website.com/referral-partners/?firstname=Admintest&surname=test&=emailtest@c.com
```

And my form element is that

```
[text* firstname placeholder "Enter your first name"]
```

I tried this solution but not work for me.

```
[text* firstname placeholder "Enter your first name" default:get]
```

Not working

also tried this

```
[text* firstname default:get default:post_meta "First Name"]
```

I want to add default value in firstname, Lastname and eamil all set by url.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Get the values from URL using $_GET request and set it in some hidden input. After that use jQuery to get the values of the hidden input and set it in the contact form elements.

Comment: Yes done this by JQuery .